# Firebase read are returning permission_denied when I'm logged with password

Tags: angularfire, firebase-security, firebase-authentication

I'm getting permission_denied when I tried to read the user-mappings data with a "authentication with password", however I'm be able to read if I'm logged with my linkedin. I whould like to know what I'm doing wrong?

This is my structure of Data and Rules:

```
//Firebase Data
user-mappings: {
  linkedin: {
    MyLikedinID: {
      user: {
        uid: "simplelogin:1"
      }
    }
  }
}

//Firebase Rules
"user-mappings": {
  "linkedin": {
    "$linkedin_uid": {
      ".read": "auth !== null && (
        (auth.provider === 'linkedin' && auth.id === $linkedin_uid) ||
        (auth.uid === data.child('user/uid').val())
      )",
      ".write": "true"
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, I'm trying to access the "user-mappings/linkedin/$linkedin_uid" data when I'm logged with email and password.

My code that do that is:

```
//Login

auth.$authWithPassword(user).then(function(authDataResult) {
  //Some code here
}).catch(function(error) {
  //Some code here
});

//Get user-mappings

var objRef = self.getRef('/user-mappings/linkedin/MyLinkedinID');
var obj = $firebaseObject(objRef);
obj.$loaded().then(function(data) {
  //When I do this, I gor the permission_denied error
});
```

Comment: Without seeing the (minimal) code that triggers the error and some (minimal) sample data that it triggers on, it is hard to parse what you're trying and why it's failing. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also note that Firebase doesn't come with a built-in LinkedIn provider. So please be explicit whether you've set that up as a custom auth provider.

Comment: I added your code to your question. Feel free to remove the comment that contains it. Multi-line code in comments is never readable, which is why StackOverflow has a handy "edit" button under all questions and answers.

Comment: I am newbie in stackoverflow, I'm sorry for my mistakes.

Comment: No problem. You're picking up steam quickly. We'll get through this. Possible answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's still not completely clear, but my best guess is that you're trying to load the data before the user is authenticated. If that is the case, it is normally easiest to see what's going on by adding some logging:

```
//Login
console.log('starting auth');
auth.$authWithPassword(user).then(function(authDataResult) {
  console.log('authenticated');
  //Some code here
}).catch(function(error) {
  //Some code here
});

//Get user-mappings

console.log('getting user mappings');
var objRef = self.getRef('/user-mappings/linkedin/MyLinkedinID');
var obj = $firebaseObject(objRef);
obj.$loaded().then(function(data) {
  console.log('user mappings gotten');
  //When I do this, I got the permission_denied error
});
```

If my guess is correct, your output will be in this order:

```
starting auth
getting user mappings
user mappings gotten
authenticated
```

So the loading of the user mappings is started before the user authentication has completed. This happens because the user authentication happens *asynchronously*.

To solve the problem you should move any code that requires the user to be authenticated into the promise that resolves when the user authentication has completed:

```
//Login
console.log('starting auth');
auth.$authWithPassword(user).then(function(authDataResult) {
  console.log('authenticated');

  //Get user-mappings
  console.log('getting user mappings');
  var objRef = self.getRef('/user-mappings/linkedin/MyLinkedinID');
  var obj = $firebaseObject(objRef);
  obj.$loaded().then(function(data) {
    console.log('user mappings gotten');
    //When I do this, I got the permission_denied error
  });

  //Some code here
}).catch(function(error) {
  //Some code here
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your support! Works perfectly.